# Deploy CodeIgniter Php app on heroku

Tags: php, codeigniter, heroku

I am trying to deploy a php application having CodeIgniter as a framework in heroku.

I followed the steps [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#local-workstation-setup) until the "Process and dyno tuning" part and managed to deploy my application. The first page works fine, but that's all. For any other page with codeigniter links(/index.php/home/link/ for the home controller, link action) I try to access, the server renders me the same first page. I thought that CI requires some of heroku extensions but [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/requirements.html) it says it only needs php. Do you happen to know what extensions do i have to provide?

The link to the website is [this](http://openbuilding.herokuapp.com/), and a test url should be [this](http://openbuilding.herokuapp.com/index.php/test/index)

Comment: Can you show project structure and `Procfile`? I'm trying to deploy code igniter on Heroku with code 404 when I access base and any other url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is defiantly a URI issue, Please try switching `$config['uri_protocol']`

from AUTO to any of the available modes until you get it fixed.

If you need a fast fix for this, just add `?` for your index.php urls so it will be like this

```
index.php?/locations/get
```

but fixing this through the 'uri_protocol' thing is better.

Comment: I can see it works with ? thought, with auto uri. I'll comment back when I can make everything work

Comment: Ok, my bad. Setting uri_protocol to PATH_INFO fixes the links. Thank you ! I'll come back after I set the database too.

Comment: had some problems with database too, i had to install cleardb, then had to enable composer and mysql extension in composer, but after that it worked. thank you.